Solve the functional equation for all functions defined under non-negative integers
Solve functional equation for all functions $f:\mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$ with all non-negative integers $m,n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ that satisfy:
$$(m+n+1)f(mn)=mf(m+n).$$
Setting $(n,m) \rightarrow (m,n)$ gives us: $$mf(m+n)=nf(n+m) \Rightarrow (m-n)f(m+n)=0.$$
$$\Rightarrow \{m=n\} \vee \{f(m+n)=0\}.$$
Case 1, $f(m+n)=0:$
$$\forall t\in \mathbb{N}_0,\exists (m,n)\in \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0: t=m+n.$$
$$ \Rightarrow \forall t\in \mathbb{N}_0: f(t)=0.$$
Checking the solution.
$$\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}_0: (m+n+1)\cdot 0 = m\cdot 0 \Rightarrow 0=0. $$
We prove that the function fits the equation.
Case 2, $m=n:$
$$ (2n+1)f(n^2)=nf(2n). $$
Setting $n=0: f(0)=0.$ The value is achieved, we move on with natural numbers $n\in \mathbb{N}, f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0.$
We can observe that $gcd(2n+1,n)=gcd(1,n)=1$, so $(2n+1)|f(2n), \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$
We rewrite function $f=f_0$ as $f(2n)=f_0(2n)=(2n+1)f_1(2n)$ for some function $f_1:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0.$
Then the functional equation becomes:
$$(2n+1)\{(n^2+1)f_1(n^2)\}=n\{(2n+1)f_1(2n)\}.$$
$$\Rightarrow (n^2+1)f_1(n^2)=nf_1(2n).$$
Again we can observe that $gcd(n^2+1,n)=1$ and $(n^2+1)|f_1(2n)$. We rewrite function $f_1$ as $f_1(2n)=\left( \frac{(2n)^2}{4}+1 \right) f_2(2n)=(n^2+1)f_2(2n)$ for some function $f_2:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0.$
$$\Rightarrow (n^2+1)\left\{\left(\frac{n^4}{4}+1\right)f_2(n^2)\right\}=n\{(n^2+1)f_2(2n)\}.$$
$$\Rightarrow \left(\frac{n^4}{4}+1\right)f_2(n^2)=nf_2(2n).$$
If this process continued, we could observe that $\forall j\in \mathbb{N}_0, f_j(2n)$ must be divisible by $2^{j}$ order polynomial. Meaning that if $f$ is divisible by polynomial $P_k(n)$, of order $k$, it must be divisible by polynomial $P_{2k}(n)$.
Let us assume that such function $f(2n)$ exists. Then $f(2n)$ is divisible by the largest $k_{th}$ order polynomial $P_k(n)$. But then it also must be divisible by $P_{2k}(n)$ which is higher order than $P_k(n)$ that $f(2n)$ is at most divisible by. We get the contradiction.
This proof for Case 2 still looks ambiguous because of greatest common divisor part for all polynomials is not given and rewriting functions this way is not clear proof. Therefore, I ask for help to add insights for solving the functional equation from the very beggining.

Do you actually need case 2 because even though for $m=n$, the sum $m+n$ can still always be written in the form $p+q=2m$ with $p\ne q$, then by case $1$, it has to be $0$ also, so the only case is to find $f(0)$?

That's the wrong way of using that first conclusion. What you have is that if $ m \neq n$, then $f(m+n) = 0 $. Use this to show that for $ k \geq 1$, $f(k) = 0 $. Then, what is $f(0)$?

You have $(m-n)f(m+n)=0$. So if $k$ can be written as a sum of two distinct parts, then $f(k)=0$. The only natural which cannot be written this way is zero. This means $f(n)=0$ for $n>0$. Setting $m=n=0$ in the functional equation gives $f(0)=0$.
